# Posts matching query does not exist

Tags: django

Ребят, подскажите в чем проблема? Какие способы решения? Передаю slug в urls и пытаюсь отфильтровать статьи по слагу категории.

При переходе на страницу категории выдает ошибку:

```
DoesNotExist at /category/kino/
Posts matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/kino/
Django Version: 1.10.3
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Posts matching query does not exist.
```

views.py

```
def get_post(request, post_slug):

    post = Posts.objects.get(post_slug=post_slug)
    return render(request, 'page.html', {'post':post})


def get_category(request, category_slug):

    cat_id = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
    posts = Posts.objects.order_by('-pub_date').filter(id=cat_id, is_active=True)
    return render(request, 'category.html', {'posts':posts})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', index, name='home'),
    url(r'^(?P<post_slug>\S+)/$', get_post, name='post'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_slug>\S+)/$', get_category, name='category'),
]
```

models.py

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Статьи'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Статьи'

    title = models.CharField(max_length=160, verbose_name='Заголовок')
    body = models.TextField(verbose_name='Текст статьи')
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=u'Дата создания', editable=False)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=u'Дата публикации')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Активация')
    post_slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s'%(self.title, str(self.create_date))

class Category(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Категория'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Категории'

    title = models.CharField(max_length=160, verbose_name='Название категории')
    parenth = models.ForeignKey('self', default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(unique=True, populate_from='title')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s (%s)'%(self.title, self.slug)
```

Comment: .фывафывафавфыафыф

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DoesNotExist - исключение, вызывается когда не обнаружилось запрашиваемой записи в БД.

Попробуйте юрл поправить, мне кажется, что у вас вызывается третий вместо четвёртого.

```
url(r'^(?P<post_slug>\[-\w]+)/$', get_post, name='post'),
url(r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', get_category, name='category'),
```

\w - это буква, цифра или знак подчёркивания.

Comment: Такая проблема, что если делаю S+ в urlке для категории, то работает отлично, т.к w+ не обрабатывает символ " - " (дефис). Если же стоит S+ и в урл статьи, то статья работает, а категория нет. если ставлю w+ в статье, то она не открывается, выдает ошибку урла. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вообщем решилось всё с оставлением S+ у обоих urlок, но только Вьюху и Урл категории я переместил наверх, поставил первее чем вызов статьи. И всё заработало. Я так и не понял, что произошло, почему приоритеты разве считаются? Хотелось бы понять, почему заработало, осознать.

Comment: Да, всё правильно, движок выбирает первое, что подошло.

Comment: Если нужно добавить тире, то надо в квадратные скобки взять допустимые символы.

Comment: Да вроде с тире вполне норм справляется просто S+. А почему он считал подходящим: url(r'^(?P<post_slug>\[-\w]+)/$', get_post, name='post') ?Тут совершенно разнтое же и контроллер и пост слаг.

Comment: Насколько я помню, S принимает любой символ кроме пробела. Тоесть включая слеши в адресной строке.