# Не могу зайти в админку django, когда использую slug

Tags: django, backend, site

Новичок в backend-е. В коде использовал slug. После того как пишу /admin ошибка: Post matching query does not exist.

Comment: Может ответ на [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594157/posts-matching-query-does-not-exist) на что-то натолкнет? И добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow. Будет лучше, если дополните вопрос ПОЛНЫМ текстом ошибки, т.е. весь стектрейс или http-ответ, что бы там ни было. Плюс не помешало бы совсем немного кода, [исключительно того, который относится к проблеме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Очень похоже, что в `urls.py` неправильно настроена маршрутизация для различных страниц, если покажешь содержимое этого файла можно будет сказать что-то конкретней